# Installing MySQL in CentOS 6.2 with RAID 1

Tags: mysql, centos, raid1

Is the installation of MySQL in CentOS with RAID1 the same as that of none? If not, what are the changes in the process of installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference at all. You should use exactly the same yum commands

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

which should also install the mysql package that provides the clients and shared libraries etc.